# Pop up window address bar is not consitent in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, window.open

I have below code:

**HTML**

```
<p>Click the button to open an about:blank page in a new browser window that is 200px wide and 100px tall.</p>
<button onclick="popitup2()">Open Window</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function popitup2() {
    newwindow2 = window.open('', 'name', 'height=200,width=150');
    var tmp = newwindow2.document;
    tmp.write('<html><head><title>popup</title>');
    tmp.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="js.css">');
    tmp.write('</head><body><p>this is once again a popup.</p>');
    tmp.write('<p><a href="javascript:alert(self.location.href)">view location</a>.</p>');
    tmp.write('<p><a href="javascript:self.close()">close</a> the popup.</p>');
    tmp.write('</body></html>');
    tmp.close();
}
```

When I run this in Firefox: popup window has address bar like "http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit_view.asp?x=0.695266304636076"

When I run the same in Chrome: popup window has address bar like "about:blank"

My question is:

Why it is different for two browsers even though I'm using the same code snippet?
How to make the common address bar(url) for popup window across all browsers?

Even my application is having this issue.
I am very curious to know the root cause for this. Can anyone please explain me?

Comment: `Why it is different for two browsers even though i am using the same code snippet?` Welcome to web development.

Comment: Hahahaha, finally I found someone as sarcastic as me! :D @Jack :D

Answer (score 1):

You're going to notice little inconsistencies like this a LOT as you get into working with web development -- what's important to keep in mind is that while HTML/CSS/Javascript all have written specifications and standards, it's up to the browser manufacturers to implement those standards, and they often choose to do so in ways that may vary in small (or large!) ways between one browser and another. You'll notice that on some mobile browsers such as that on the iPhone (and from what I hear, new canary versions of Chrome), the address bar doesn't even display the full URL for normal pages, but rather just the root address of the site. It's something we as web developers just have to live with -- if it's not a hard and fast part of the technical specification, we can't always expect things to behave consistently or in the way we'd expect it to.

Comment: Is there any way to make them consistent? any approach ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. As I said -- there's always going to be things that are just implemented arbitrarily, and unless someone can correct me, I think that this might be one of them.